# Validation is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I did the valition, but when I put the right numbers it gaves me an error that say "Max Weight should be greater than the Min Weight" but it isnt greater :c

this is the code if the validation

```js
if (input.weightMin > input.weightMax) {
      errors.weightMax = "Peso maximo deberia ser mayor que el peso minimo";
    }
```

this is the code of the hmtl

```html
<div className={d.contfilt}>
            <label>Peso mínimo:</label>
            <input
              className={d.inp}
              type="text"
              value={input.weightMin}
              name="weightMin"
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Kg"
            />
            {errors.weightMin && <p className={d.error}>{errors.weightMin}</p>}
          </div>
          <div className={d.contfilt}>
            <label>Peso máximo:</label>
            <input
              className={d.inp}
              type="text"
              value={input.weightMax}
              name="weightMax"
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Kg"
            />
            {errors.weightMax && <p className={d.error}>{errors.weightMax}</p>}
          </div>
```

this is the pic of the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a75g7.png)

Comment: What is the default value of errors.weightMax ?

Comment: const [input, setInput] = useState({
    name: "",
    heightMin: "",
    heightMax: "",
    weightMin: "",
    weightMax: "",
    life_span: "",
    image: "",
    temperament: [],
  }); (Is empy 8(  )

Comment: You probably need to convert the values into numbers first. `"20"` is greater than `"100"` because 2 comes later in the alphabet.

Comment: Solved, I just added a parseInt hahaha

Comment: Yep, feel free to remove the question yourself